# Can I pack a npx command to exe file?

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

like the command:

```bash
npx https://gist.github.com/items/xxxxxx
```

How can I pack the command to the `.exe` file, even the user doesn't have a npx(node).

Comment: [ElectronJS](https://www.electronjs.org/) lets users execute nodejs without node on windows.